Primitive of Splitting Field of Rational Polynomial
Let $p\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be irreducible and let $K$ be the splitting field of $p$. Since $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, there exists an irreducible $q\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $K=\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle q(x)\rangle$, by the primitive element theorem.
Is a way to construct such a $q$ from $p$?
I note that the splitting field $K \neq \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ in general. For example, if $p(x)=x^3-2$ then the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^{6}+9 x^{4}-4 x^{3}+27 x^{2}+36 x+31\rangle = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}+i\sqrt{3}] $. So, we cannot always use $q=p$.

The polynomial $q$ can be taken as the minimal polynomial of some $\mathbb Q$-linear combination of the roots of $p$ (or of any other finite set of genarators).
Let $\alpha,\beta$ be roots of irreducible polynomials $r\in\mathbb Q[x]$ and $p$, respectively. Then for a "general" choice of $t\in\mathbb Q$, there is no root $\gamma\ne\beta$ of $p$ such that $\alpha+t\beta-t\gamma$ is a root of $r$. This is because the number of roots of $r,p$ is finite and two such roots $\gamma$ and $\alpha+t\beta-t\gamma$ determines $t$ uniquely. For such $t$, the greatest common divisor of $p(x)$ and $r(\alpha+t\beta-tx)$ is $x-\beta$, whose coeffients should be in the field of coefficients $\mathbb Q(\alpha+t\beta)$ of $p(x)$ and $r(\alpha+t\beta-tx)$. This implies that $\beta\in\mathbb Q(\alpha+t\beta)$ and hence that $\alpha=(\alpha+t\beta)-t\beta\in\mathbb Q(\alpha+t\beta)$. So we have
$$\mathbb Q(\alpha,\beta)=\mathbb Q(\alpha+t\beta).$$
Continuing this way yields the expression of the splitting field of $p$ as a simple extension
$$\mathbb Q(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)=\mathbb Q(\alpha_1+t_2\alpha_2+\cdots+t_n\alpha_n)$$
where $\alpha_1=\alpha$, $\alpha_2=\beta$, $t_2=t$ and $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are the distinct roots of $p$. Note: this is a constructive proof of the primitive element theorem and works also for any finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ which need not be normal (i.e., a splitting field).
For your example
$$p(x)=x^3-2$$
the roots are $\sqrt[3]2,\omega\sqrt[3]2,\omega^2\sqrt[3]2$ where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity. Fortunately the splitting field can also be generated by $\sqrt[3]2$ and $i\sqrt3$. Try $t=1$. The only conjugate of $i\sqrt3$ other than itself is $-i\sqrt3$, and
$$\sqrt[3]2+i\sqrt3-(-i\sqrt3)=\sqrt[3]2+2i\sqrt3$$
is not a conjugate of $\sqrt[3]2$. Hence $\sqrt[3]2+i\sqrt3$ is the right choice and its minimal polynomial $q$ is what we wanted.
